# DCOM Server Process Launcher service is in disabled state in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, dcom

Due to a long battle with a computer virus, my DCOM Server Process is disabled from services.msc in Windows 7. Is there any way to bring it back?

I don't want to:

1. Reformat - lost time
2. Do an in place upgrade - lost time
3. System Restore - get reinfected by the virus

Is there any other to get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DCOM Service Launcher service properties are normally greyed out (no control from Services.msc).

If it is showing as "Disabled" for the startup type you could try navigating in RegEdit to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\DcomLaunch` and set the `Start` key to `2` (for Automatic), then reboot.